# Creating own Livestream Website

Tags: web, stream

I'm about to create my own website to stream my livestream and maybe livestreams of other friends I have to. Now I'd like to know if there are any tools or CMS's which are like specialised in livestream pages/websites.
Is there any way I can make a secured website with the tools which are free to download or do I have to code them myself in php/html?

*Edit:* I'm planning on streaming video with audio. 
Which is from one to many (1 streamer - more watchers)
And since I'm (a bit) lazy, I'd like to know if there is any source/tool/CMS which makes it easy to create a secure website to use as a streaming website. So when I start my stream, all people which are on my website are able to see the stream with video and audio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be more specific.  What do you mean by "livestream"?  You want to stream video?  Audio?  From what kinds of sources?  Is this a stream going from one user to another?  One user to many?  And.. what specifically have you tried and what trouble are you having?

Comment: I've editted it, hope this explains a bit more if needed.

Comment: Alright, so video streaming.  And the source... does that have to be web based?  What kind of content are you streaming?  Screenshots?  Web cams?  What quality of video do you need?  What is your latency requirement?  Do you need the ability to record/archive video being streamed?  And again, what have you looked into and tried?

Comment: I'm planning on streaming on twitch, but redirected to my website by using the sharing code(s) twitch can provide you.
I'm streaming mainly Videogame Gameplay. If it is possible I'd like to not lose that much latency by doing this. 
I've tried Yoomla, but it didn'\t work as I wanted. 
Hope this clears it up a bit.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cms systems are only, as the name suggests, content management systems. What you display there is only a factor of codimg. But first you need your streaming data. Be aware that streaming on twitch is a serverside high tech stuff, because you n3ed to compress the data that gets broadcastet. Your main problem will be the bandwidth, because you may need a cluster of servers with an intelligent loadballancer to handle the load. Why you dont just stream with twitch itself...those giys put manyears in their stuff, dont expect to reproduce that in some minutes.